# How do I call a function that is apart of an object that is housed in an array?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am running into an issue with my program. I am trying to call a function that is a part of an object housed in an array. I am having trouble with calling the function properly.

```
//Declare Array that will Host Projects
let allProjects = [];

//Create Parent Class that creates objects (Project)
class Project {

constructor(projTitle, projDescription, projHours, projReserved) {

    //Declare variables
    this._name = projTitle;
    this._description =  projDescription;
    this._hours = projHours;
    this._reserved = projReserved;

    //Send newly constructed object directly to next space in array.
    allProjects.push(this);

    //TODO Reserve function
    function reserve() {
        if (this._reserved === false ) {
            this._reserved === true;
        } else {
            console.log('The project you are trying to reserve has already been taken.');
        }
    }
    };
}

//Call the reserve function of the object in array index 0.
allProjects[0].reserve();
```

When I run the program I get the following error:

```
allProjects[0].reserve();
           ^
TypeError: allProjects[0].reserve is not a function
```

Any help and/or tips are taken into consideration and appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `reserve` function to be callable on the instantiated object, you should put it on the prototype. Also, `===` is comparison, not assignment; change

```
this._reserved === true;
```

to

```
this._reserved = true;
```

In full:

```
class Project {
  constructor(projTitle, projDescription, projHours, projReserved) {
    this._name = projTitle;
    this._description =  projDescription;
    this._hours = projHours;
    this._reserved = projReserved;

    allProjects.push(this);
  }
  reserve() {
    if (this._reserved === false ) {
      this._reserved = true;
    } else {
      console.log('The project you are trying to reserve has already been taken.');
    }
  }
}
```

Another option that is technically correct but probably not efficient (might have been what you were trying to do originally) would be to assign the function to the instantiated object's `reserve` property in the constructor:

```
class Project {
  constructor(projTitle, projDescription, projHours, projReserved) {
    this._name = projTitle;
    this._description =  projDescription;
    this._hours = projHours;
    this._reserved = projReserved;

    allProjects.push(this);
    this.reserve = function() {
      if (this._reserved === false ) {
        this._reserved = true;
      } else {
        console.log('The project you are trying to reserve has already been taken.');
      }
    }
  }
}
```